# Adding a sample plugin into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin that i want to integrate with my Eclipse IDE . The plugin I downloaded from the internet consists of two jar files, namely:

```
org.eclipse.dg.ex.core_1.0.jar
org.eclipse.dg.ex.ui_1.0.jar
```

How do i get them into my IDE? I tried putting them in the Eclipse `dropins` folder, but i think this may be incorrect .

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

The definitely belong in the eclipse/plugins folder.  You will likely need to restart eclipse as well.

Comment: Yes i have restarted the eclipse but these plugins dont seem to have any effect :( I am not sure how to re-create a plugin from just 2 jar files . I feel a bit lost here .

Comment: if you are using Eclipse 3.4 or later, you should not add plugins (using file system operations) to the plugins directory, instead they belong in the dropins folder.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the plugin in the `dropins` directory is correct! It does not belong in the plugins directory. Ever since `p2` was added to Eclipse, the dropins directory was introduced as a means to install new plugins via general file system operations

```
The dropins folder is configured to be scanned during startup. Thus the dropins folder can be used    
much like the plugins directory was used in the past.
```

[Here](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html) is some information about the `dropins` folder. This also includes valid layouts for a plugin that lives in `dropins`. Have a look. It's very likely you just need to 'layout' the plugin properly.